# Commercial electric motor with integrated torque sensor and torque control

Tags: sensors, torque, actuator

Are there any commercial solutions for electric rotary motors with integrated torque sensor and torque control?

I'm only aware of www.sensodrive.de which are essentially the drives used in the DLR/Kuka Light Weight Robot. But those use harmonic drives (gear ratio of 1/100, < 10 RPM). I need something with much higher RPM and lower torque range (less than 0.01 Nm resolution would be good). Up to 300-1000 RPM but no more than 5 Nm torque is required. So something with a small gear ratio or no gear at all.

Comment: Do you need these sensors etc. to be integrated into the motors, or the drivers? Can you give more information on your specific application? This seems like a [recommendation question](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/the-engineering-se-position-on-recommendation-finding-stuff-questions) which is specifically described as off-topic in our [help centre](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)